# mixing roman numbers and arabic numbers in page numbering in libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

In libreoffice, my first couple pages should have page numbering in roman numbers: i, ii
Then, after a couple of pages later, it should start with arabic numbers; 1, 2 ...

I applied what is written here: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers#To_Start_With_a_Defined_Page_Number

And, now it goes like 1,2,1,2,3,4... which is only one part of what I want. It should go like this; i,ii,1,2,3,4...

Comment: Did you take care of https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers#Using_Different_Page_Number_Styles ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've not even made it to the first point (1, 2, 1, 2, 3), failing to make any sense of the instructions at https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers#To_Start_With_a_Defined_Page_Number ...